# Get service name from QDBusConnection with Qt5

Tags: qt, signals-slots, dbus, qdbus, qtdbus

Our framework is recently updating to Qt5 from Qt4.
But here we got some problems on the d-bus event processing.

The original code `QDBusConnection::sender().name()` return empty string. And the official suggested substitute way `QDBusContext::connection()` return something like "1.40", "1.101" (should be address or something, and is correct).

We also try to use `msg.service()` where msg is a `QDBusMessage`, but still get the former address.

We need to get its name like `com.stackoverflow.HelpMe` which we send into the `QDBusConnection::connect()` to insure that we can distinguish different services even if the d-bus services are restarted which may make the address change.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well....... in fact, the official suggested substitute way `QDBusContext::connection()` can work.
We don't know why the previous try got different result.